# Uninitialized Constant Message::ThreadId

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning ruby and was trying to create a messaging system. Here is how I create a new message in the database. It doesn't work.

```
@message = Message.new
@message.thread_id = @thread.id
@message.text = params[:message]
if @message.save
  @thread.load_thread
  render json: {:success => "true", :thread => @thread}
end
```

This is the error I keep getting

```
uninitialized constant Message::ThreadId
```

In the database/model, I have a field called `thread_id`. Unable to understand whats happening here. Can anyone explain me?

**EDIT**:

*Message Model*:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thread_id
  def new
  end

  def new(thread_id,message_text)
  end
end
```

The message model migration is :

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.references :thread, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the Message model ?

Comment: @monu: Update. Please have a look